# Changing paragraphs text based on their id

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <p id="1"></p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p id="2"></p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p id="3"></p>
   </li>
</ul>

for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {

var msg = "hello" + i;
$('ul li p').text(msg);
}
```

I want to create a variable that will shift its value by the id of the paragraph. Meaning, that first p will say hello1, second hello2 etc. I know it`s possible in a click function by doing $(this).attr('id'), but is there someway do do it outside that function, since i need it to run on page load

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li p').each(function(index) {
     var msg = "hello" + $(this).attr('id');
     $(this).text(msg);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>
      <p id="1"></p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p id="2"></p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p id="3"></p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {

var msg = "hello" + i;
$('ul li p').text(msg);
}
})
```